# POST Request from Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, macros, http-post

*Necesito obtener los datos de un afiliado a la AFP para ello realizo una consulta POST a la URL de la siguiente rutina Excel VBA.*

```
Sub RequestPOST()
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim reqBody,URL As String
    
    URL = "https://www2.sbs.gob.pe/afiliados/paginas/Consulta.aspx"
    req.Open "POST", URL, False
    req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    
    reqBody = "ctl00$cphContent$afil=RadioButton1&ctl00$cphContent$dbDocumento=00&ctl00$cphContent$txtDocumento=74035206"
    
    'Donde el cuerpo de la consulta (reqBody) está compuesto por:
    'ctl00$cphContent$afil=RadioButton1 Es un OptionButton por Documento de Identificación
    'ctl00$cphContent$dbDocumento=00 Es un Selector por Tipo de Documento (DNI)
    'ctl00$cphContent$txtDocumento=74035206 Es un TextBox por el numero de Documento (DNI) del afiliado al AFP.
    
    req.send reqBody
    Debug.Print req.responseText
    MsgBox req.Status & " -" & req.StatusText, vbInformation, "Titulo"
    
End Sub
```

*Sin embargo cuando realizo la consulta no obtengo los datos del afiliado.*

Comment: Cómo la estás intentando hacer? Cuál es la respuesta obtenida (o el error) y cuál es la respuesta esperada? Edita tu pregunta y añade esta información

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque tu petición no está siguiendo la redirección que indica el sitio que estás buscando consultar. No va a ser un proceso sencillo usando Excel, pero se puede.

Cuando tú ingresas a ese formulario Consulta.aspx e ingresas los datos de prueba que indicas en tu código, la página responde con un HTTP 302 (una redirección) a Documento.aspx, que es donde te mostrará el resultado de tu consulta. Con probarlo en tu navegador lo puedes comprobar tú mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si el cliente no sigue la redirección usando las cookies del sitio, no va a funcionar.

Yo haría el POST que estás haciendo, luego parsearía el contenido de las cookies que te entrega y luego haría un GET a Documento.aspx fijando previamente el valor de las cookies que parseaste, al igual que el referer. Algo como lo que hacen en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35908113/236345). Así, mantendrás la sesión en el servidor destino y te mostrará el resultado, haciéndole saber que es el mismo cliente el que está consultando las dos URL.

Fíjate bien en no poner exactamente las cookies del ejemplo en el enlace que te comparto. Deben ser las que entrega el servidor que estás consultando. Yo veo que el servidor entrega:

> Set-Cookie    ASP.NET_SessionId=s32qz31hipjv5pvmh2ufq5ch; path=/;
> HttpOnly
>
> Set-Cookie TS0101bca0=019955ae16c413badc96e68e2033ee206ce28be82e4d1f9602def6d7c604de76dd0674ed33df7761be949c0671017719086a570fce9594536f9ec4ab018cc49a0f6674b07a63b5966c841d57c5f2623bbc9b14b09c;
> Path=/; Domain=.www2.sbs.gob.pe; Secure; HTTPOnly

Mira los headers que envía el navegador en la primera petición (la que estás intentando hacer)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los que retorna el servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego, cuando el navegador sigue la redirección a Documento.aspx, envía estos headers

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta. Cuando realizo la consulta POST para obtener las Cookies, con la siguiente rutina:

```
Sub RequestPOST()
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim reqBody As String
Dim URL As String
Dim strCookies As String
    
    URL = "https://www2.sbs.gob.pe/afiliados/paginas/Consulta.aspx"
    req.Open "POST", URL, False
    req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"       
 

reqBody="ctl00$cphContent$afil=RadioButton1&ctl00$cphContent$dbDocumento=00&ctl00$cphContent$txtDocumento=48265129&ctl00$cphContent$btnBuscar=Buscar"
        
    req.send reqBody
    strCookies = req.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
        
End Sub
```

Obtengo este resultado de req.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"):

*incap_ses_785_2355501=PaN3coFS8T5os0XlfuHkCvvIOF8AAAAA2hSdu9Xf8txbCHyWRQlAsw==; path=/; Domain=.sbs.gob.pe*

Creo que el problema está en el cuerpo de la consulta POST.